# SQL Double Conditional SELECT without repeating values within a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, conditional-statements

Given a table **Details**:

| Lanugage | IsDefault | PropertyName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| en | False | Property 119 |
| es | True | Property 119 |
| fr | False | Property 119 |
| en | False | Property 14 |
| es | True | Property 14 |
| en | False | Property 16 |
| es | True | Property 16 |

I am trying to `SELECT * FROM Details WHERE [Language] = 'fr'`, then `SELECT * FROM Details WHERE [Language] != 'fr' AND IsDefault = 1` without repeating `PropertyName` in the results if it was already selected in `SELECT * FROM Details WHERE [Language] = 'fr'`.

Expected Result is:

| Lanugage | IsDefault | PropertyName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fr | False | Property 119 |
| es | True | Property 14 |
| es | True | Property 16 |

However I have tried many things (`UNION`, `NOT EXISTS` ...) are the result for me is always:

| Lanugage | IsDefault | PropertyName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fr | False | Property 119 |
| es | True | Property 119 |
| es | True | Property 14 |
| es | True | Property 16 |

How would one achieve this?

Comment: It can be done, but how would you choose which of the two languages you are going to show. For propert 119, should there be fr or es?

Comment: Hi @Divisadero thank you for your time. For Property 119 it should be 'FR' first since it exists for this Language, and it should then take IsDefault = 1 for the rest where the Language is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyName
                                 ORDER BY CASE LANGUAGE WHEN 'fr' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) rn
    FROM Details
    WHERE Language = 'fr' OR IsDefault = 1
)

SELECT Language, IsDefault, PropertyName
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The logic above is to use a single query to generate a result set with all candidate records.  We also turn out a row number, per property, based on an ordering where French properties always rank higher (read: row number is lower) than properties from all other countries.  We retain only one record per property.

Comment: One possible modification you might want to make would be to add logic which determines _which_ other country's record gets included should a property have no French record.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for UNION ALL also to achieve the result.

```sql
;cte_fr AS
(SELECT PropertyName, IsDefault, Language
FROM Details
WHERE Language = 'Fr')
select propertyname, isdefault,language from cte_fr
UNION ALL
select propertyname, isdefault,language from Details as d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
select * from CTE_FR
WHERE PropertyName = d.PropertyName
)
and d.IsDefault = 1;
```

| propertyname | isdefault | language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Property 119 | 0 | fr |
| Property 14 | 1 | es |
| Property 16 | 1 | es |

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired results simply by grouping,

```
select  Max([Language]), Max(IsDefault), Max(PropertyName)
from Details
where [language]='fr' or ([language] !='fr' and isdefault='True')
group by PropertyName
```